# Does a mayonnaise have longer shelf life with egg white only as opposed to yolk?

Tags: food-safety, eggs, storage-lifetime, mayonnaise

I am working on a mayonnaise recipe, that could have at least 2 -3 weeks shelf life (refrigerated).
I have access to pasteurized egg yolk, and white.

I believe there will be a longer shelf life using egg white only, but how to evaluate it accurately?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi, I made your question title better match the specific question in the body text. A general question on the shelf life of mayonnaise would have to be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: If you're not using egg yolk, what is the emulsifier?

Comment: Egg white can work as emulsifier too

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference in the shelf life of mayonnaise made with egg whites, or egg yolks, or whole eggs. Since you are using pasteurized eggs, this counts as a standard cooked dish, and the shelf life is 3-5 days in the fridge. It would be 1-2 days for raw eggs.

You cannot evaluate the safe shelf life of a food by yourself. In principle, one could commission a microbiological study to prove that a given recipe is somehow longer lasting than one would expect from its general category. That is likely to cost more than hiring a cook to make you a daily batch of mayonnaise for the next few years.

For more information on food safety, I would suggest that you also look at the extensive information we have compiled on the topic: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
After checking with my supplier egg yolk have 5 days shelf life, and egg white 10 days.
What could be used as an emulsifier to replace the egg?

Comment: The shelf life of each ingredient doesn't matter. The new dish has its own shelf life, which can easily be shorter than the shelf life of the ingredients.